ProgressBar for UniQuery with break button
We have a task to create a progress bar for executing a query to a database. As components of access to the database, we use UniDAC
The form should have a "Break" button, by which you can stop executing the query at any time, and a progress bar that will display the process of receiving data
The application has complex queries that sometimes spend a significant amount of time on building a plan, during this time in NonBlocking mode UniQuery freezes together with the application and does not allow you to perform any actions. Therefore, we execute the query in a separate thread. But in the thread, UniQuery behaves unstable, various errors occur.
Has anyone solved a similar problem? Perhaps not with UniDAC? I would be very grateful for an example
attempt to start UniQuery in NonBlocking mode causes the form to appear only 5 seconds after it has completed its work WAITFOR
UniQuery1.SQL.Text := 'WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:05''; SELECT top(200000) * FROM dbo.MYTable';
UniQuery1.SpecificOptions.Values['NonBlocking'] := 'TRUE';
UniQuery1.Open;
MyProgressForm.ShowModal;


Executing long query in a separate thread is the right approach.You claim that when you do so the query behaves unstable. Can you please elaborate on this. What instability do you encounter?

the component works unstably when trying to interrupt the execution of a request at different stages of execution, various errors occur. interruption of work is implemented as follows:
if UniQuery1.RecordCount = 0 then UniQuery1.Close else UniQuery1.BreakExec
There are various errors, for example: "Not enough timers available"

I execute thousands of queryes in threads using Uniquery component with no problem. I think you are sharing a connection object with the main thread. Each thread must have its own connection to avoid racing conditions between threads. Try creating a new connection inside the thread and using this connection to run the query.

I tried to use a new Connection in the thread.
After I received data in the thread, how can I return it to the main thread?
If I assign MainConnection, the UniQuery state becomes dsInactive and RecordCount=0
It also does not work to transfer a data set via the standard UniQueryMain.Assign(UniQueryThread)
How can I correctly transfer a set of received data from one UniQuery to another?

Try declaring the Uniquey in the public section of your TThread Object, run the query in the execute method. Once the execute method terminate its execution, the Terminated property of the thread object is set to True. Then you can access the query object, do what ou have to do and then free the Thread. To do this the FreeOnTerminate property of the thread object must be false.
